# Assembly for a C switch statement - how does it work?

Tags: assembly, switch-statement

I am reading a book about assembly switch statement, the code has cases/branches when the input n is case: 100, 102, 103, 104, 106. It simplified the jump table by subtracting 100 from n and then if the result is above 6, it goes to the default case in L2, Otherwise it will go to the corresponding branches that match the value in %eax.

And my questions are:

1. if so, isn't line 7 suppose to be `jmp *.L7(,%eax)` if the index of jump table is held in `%eax`?
2. And why did they change the number into unsigned in line 5 by doing `ja .L2`?

`int x` is at `%ebp+8`,`int n` at `%ebp+12`

```
 movl 8(%ebp), %edx 
 movl 12(%ebp), %eax 
 subl $100, %eax 
 cmpl $6, %eax 
 ja .L2 
 jmp *.L7(,%eax,4) 
.L2: 
 movl $0, %eax 
 jmp .L8 
.L5: 
 movl %edx, %eax 
jmp .L9 
 .L3: 
 leal (%edx,%edx,2), %eax 
 leal (%edx,%eax,4), %eax 
 jmp .L8 
.L4: 
 leal 10(%edx), %eax 
.L9: 
 addl $11, %eax 
 jmp .L8 
.L6: 
 movl %edx, %eax 
 imull %edx, %eax 
.L8:
```

Jump table:

```
.section .rodata
.align 4 Align       
.L7:
.long .L3         //Case 100: loc_A
.long .L2         //Case 101: loc_def
.long .L4         //Case 102: loc_B
.long .L5        //Case 103: loc_C
.long .L6        //Case 104: loc_D
.long .L2       //Case 105: loc_def
.long .L6        //Case 106: loc_D
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> isn't line 7 suppose to be `jmp *.L7(,%eax)` if the index of jump table is held in `%eax`?

Each entry in the jump table is a `long`, which is 4 bytes. Hence `eax` is scaled by 4.

> And why did they changed the number into unsigned in line 5 by doing `ja .L2`?

The point is to exclude any number that's less than 100 and greater than 106. I assume it's obvious how it excludes values greater than 106.

So let's say `n` was less than 100, e.g. 99. If we then subtract 100 from that we get -1, which when viewed as an unsigned 32-bit value is 4294967295, which is obviously "above" 6, and the jump to `.L2` is taken like it should.

```
subl $100, %eax   ; eax = 99-100 == -1
cmpl $6, %eax     ; set flags based on -1 - 6 == -7 => ZF=0 and CF=0
ja .L2            ; jump if ZF=0 and CF=0
```

Comment: Is it because when we change signed integer to unsigned integer, the value of the unsigned integer would be changed to some large number because signed integer uses two's complement while unsigned is not?

Comment: Well, there isn't any actual "changing" of signs taking place. The conditional jumps are taken based on the status of certain flags. In the case of `ja` the jump will be made if ZF=0 and CF=0. The last operation that updated the flags was `cmp`, which really is a subtraction. For a subtraction to result in ZF=0 means that the operands were not equal, and to get CF=0 the first operand (`eax`) needs to be unsigned greater than or equal to the second operand (`6`). Hence my suggestion to view the value of `eax` as unsigned to make it easier to reason about what will happen.